# Convert a for loop to matrix calculation from np.matmul(1xn, nx1) to np.matmul(mxn, nxm)?

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-algebra

I have a linear algebra problem to convert a for loop to matrix calculation

```
def f():
    # w.shape = (n,1)
    # X.shape = (m,n)
    # y.shape = (m,)
    # v.shape = (n,n)
    # c is constant
    for t in range(len(X)): 
        x = X[t].reshape((1,-1))
        flag = np.dot(x, w)*y[t]
        cov = np.matmul(np.matmul(x, v), x.T)  # cov is a scalar

        if flag<1:
            b = 1.0/(cov + c)
            a = max(0.0, 1-flag) * b
            w += a*y[t]*np.matmul(v, x.T)
            v -= b*np.matmul(np.matmul(v, x.T), np.matmul(x, v))
    return w, v
```

How do I remove the for loop and replace it by matrix calculation?

Comment: `(A[mask]**2).sum(1).tolist()` should do it.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Thanks. However, I found that the question I tried to simplify actually doesn't represent the problem I have. Therefore your answer cannot solve my problem. So I updated my question. Please help again.

Answer (score 2):

You are taking the diagonal elements of the res1. So you can use $np.diagonal to fetch the diagonal elements.

```
res2 = np.diagonal(np.dot(A[mask], A[mask].T))
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I just updated the question. Maybe you had not seen it when you answered. Thanks.

Comment: `diagonal` selects a subset of the values calculated by the `dot`.  So it's not the most efficient route.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think through this step by step

```
def f():
    # w.shape = (n,1)
    # X.shape = (m,n)
    # y.shape = (m,)
    # v.shape = (n,n)
    # c is constant
    for t in range(len(X)): 
        x = X[t].reshape((1,-1))
```

`X` is (m,n), `x` is (n,) reshaped to (1,n)

```
        flag = np.dot(x, w)*y[t]
```

`flag` is `dot of (1,n) with (n,1) => (1,1) times scalar element of`y`; result scalar

How about (m,n) `X` dot with (n,1) to produce (m,1)? `(X@w)*y[:,None]` => (m,1).

Alternatively  `X@w[:,0])*y` to produce (m,) shape

```
        cov = np.matmul(np.matmul(x, v), x.T)  # cov is a scalar
```

`matmul/dot` `x` with `v`, (1,n) with (n,n)=> (1,n); and `matmul/dot` with (n,1) => (1,1)

Again using `X`: `X@v` `(m,n)@(n,n)=>(m,n)` Another (n,1) dot to produce (m,1)

```
cov = X@v@X.T


        if flag<1:
            b = 1.0/(cov + c)
            a = max(0.0, 1-flag) * b
            w += a*y[t]*np.matmul(v, x.T)
            v -= b*np.matmul(np.matmul(v, x.T), np.matmul(x, v))
```

If `flag` is (m,1) or (m,), we can't use the `if`.  But we make

```
 mask = flag < 1
 b = 1.0/(cov[mask]+c                  # (k,) (k less than m)
 a = np.amax(0.0, 1-flag[mask]) * b    # (k,)
 w = np.sum(a*y[mask]*(X[mask,:]@v), axis=?)   # ???
 v ???
```

I haven't worked out the details in the last part.  To be clear you may want to name `X[mask,:]`, `cov[mask]`, `flag[mask]`, `y[mask]`, so you now have a bunch of (p,n), and (p,) shaped arrays.

```
    return w, v
```

Comment: X@v@X.T returns shape (m, m), not (m, 1)

Comment: OK, `np.einsum('ij,jk,ki->i', X,v,X)` would get the 'diagonal` of that `(m,m)`.  `X[:,None,:]@v@X[:,:,None]` should produce a `(m,1,1)` array.  I'm adjust the dimensions of `X` so the first `m` dimension is a `batch` dimension, e.g. `(m,1,n)@(n,n)@(m,n,1)`

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out. Thanks to @hpaulj

```
        flag = X@w[:,0]*y #(m,)
        cov = (X[:,None,:]@v@X[:,:,None])[:,0,0] #(m,)

        mask = 1-flag>0   # (p,)

        b = 1.0/(cov[mask]+c)  # (p,)
        a = 1-flag[mask]*b  # (p,)

        tmp1 = a[:,None]*y[mask][:,None]*(X[mask,:]@v) # (p,n)
        w = np.sum(tmp1, axis=0).reshape(w.shape)
        tmp2 = ((v@X.T)@(X@v)).ravel()[:,None]*b  # (n^2,p)
        v = np.sum(tmp2,axis=1).reshape(v.shape)  # (n,n)
```